# Mongodb : Is there a way to add a compound index to a collection that already has a lot of documents?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

If I have a lot of data, I can't create an index
Is there a way to create a compound index?

Comment: You can create an index on an existing collection.

Comment: but already this collection has many data so i can't create index more.
Is there any other way?

Comment: You can follow instructions from here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/